# Изображение динамической матрицы с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой есть способ выводить в окне браузера динамическую матрицу из случайных чисел? Нужно, чтобы потом эти числа можно было читать/писать. Не представляю, какой элемент использовать в HTML для хранения переменных.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, вариантов навалом. Можно сделать table и методами JavaScript/JQuery перебирать ячейки, записывая или считывая данные оттуда. А можно сделать div , а в нем дочерние div, в которых элементы. По-моему два способа вполне достаточно, чтобы сделать матрицу:).

Answer (score 0):

Случайное число http://javascript.ru/Math.random

Comment: Проблема собственно не в генерации случайных чисел, а в их представлении для дальнейшей обработки и отображения на экране в браузере

Comment: @carapuz, почему бы не использовать обычный `input`?

Answer (score 0):

**Вот простенький пример матрицы 3x3 на чтение и запись:**

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo Title</title>

     <style type="text/css">
     input[type=text]{
       width:42px;
       text-align:center;
     }
     input[type=button],
     label{
       font-weight:bold;
       text-transform:lowercase;
     }
     </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
       function isCorrectRowCol(row, col){
         if(row > 0 && row<=3 && col > 0 && col<=3)
            return true;
        alert("Can not find a cell with the parameters: row = " + 
                   row + ", column = " + col +
                   ".\nRow or column can be in range from 1 to 3!!!");  
    }
    function getCellValue(){
        var row = document.getElementById("rowInput").value;
        var col = document.getElementById("colInput").value;
        if(isCorrectRowCol(row, col)){
            var cellVal = document.getElementById("r" + row + "c" + col).value;
            alert(cellVal);
        }
    }

    function setCellValue(){
        var row = document.getElementById("rowInput").value;
        var col = document.getElementById("colInput").value;
        if(isCorrectRowCol(row, col)){
            var cellVal = document.getElementById("cellInput").value;
            document.getElementById("r" + row + "c" + col).value = cellVal;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="r1c1" value="1.1"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="r1c2" value="1.2"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="r1c3" value="1.3"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="r2c1" value="2.1" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="r2c2" value="2.2" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="r2c3" value="2.3"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="r3c1" value="3.1" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="r3c2" value="3.2" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="r3c3" value="3.3" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <hr />
      <div>

        <label for="rowInput" >row:</label><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="rowInput" value="1"/>
        <label for="colInput" />col:</label><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="colInput" value="1"/>
        <input type="button" value="get" onclick="getCellValue();"/>
        <label for="cellInput" />new value:</label><input type="text" maxlength="4" id="cellInput" value="???"/>
        <input type="button" value="set" onclick="setCellValue();"/>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```